# $X$ be a non-empty subset of irrational numbers such that sum of any two elements of $X$ is rational ; then is there any upper bound for $|X|$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of irrational numbers such that sum of any two elements of $X$ is rational ; then is there any possible upper bound for the cardinality of $X$ ? Can $X$ be infinite ?( I know that $|X|$ can be $2$ ) . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ had three distinct elements, say $a,b,c$, then, since $a+b$ and $a+c$ are rational, so is their difference $b-c$.  But $b+c$ is also rational, and therefore so is $(b+c)+(b-c)=2b$.  But then $b$ is rational, contrary to hypothesis.

Comment: Brian Scott's answer, which arrived while I was typing mine, seems essentially equivalent to mine, but I'll leave mine here, only because it uses fewer symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $x,y,z\in X$. Let $q=x+y$ and $r=x+z$. Then $y=q-x$, $z=r-x$, and $y+z=q+r-2x$. If $q$ and $r$ are rational, and $x$ is irrational, can $q+r-2x$ be rational?